# How to calculate an average value with probabilities?

Tags: probability, average

So I was wondering how to calculate an average value with probabilities.

This question is regarding grades.

So I got an 18/30 in the first part of my exam that counted as 30% of my final grade. I then got a 26/30 which counted as 70% of my final grade.

How can I  calculate my average grade?

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{18}{30} \cdot 30 + \frac{26}{30}\cdot 70 = 78.66...\%$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an expected value. It is simply a mean weighted by the probabilities.